# How would i go about adding gravity into this such that the other segments are still constrained by a max distance?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been working on a project in Unity and have run into a problem that i have been researching for a few days now. My idea was to create a player character (worm) made of multiple segments that could use these segments to traverse my world (2D platformer). I tried using bones to implement this but ran into numerous errors and as looked online to find a 3D version of what i originally had in mind. I tried this and it worked great however due to it using direct methods of changing the positions of the segments, it means that the different segments are not affected by gravity.

```
public class WormFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    [SerializeField] private Transform _front;
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D _rb;

    [SerializeField] private float _distance = 1;

    [SerializeField] private float ropeLength = 1;

    [SerializeField] private Vector3 _attachmentPoint;

    private void Start()
    {
        Vector3 localAttachment = new Vector3(_distance, 0, 0);
        _attachmentPoint = transform.TransformPoint(localAttachment);
    }
    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 displacement = _attachmentPoint - _front.position;
        Vector3 rope = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(displacement, ropeLength);
        _attachmentPoint = new Vector3(_front.position.x + rope.x, _front.position.y + rope.y, 0);
        float leverlength = _distance * transform.localScale.x;

        Vector3 lever = displacement.normalized * leverlength;
        transform.position = _attachmentPoint + lever;

    }
}
```

So far i have tried using different methods like i had mentioned however was unsuccessful in making it work how i wanted to. I had also tried a few ways of manipulating the y value of the different segments to try to get their values to be affected by gravity however this was also unsuccessful.

Comment: I would guess that making segments out of rigidbodies connected by joints might work. But I would be careful putting the player, or part of the player, under to much control of the physics system since it may result in odd behaviors.

Comment: sounds like e.g. [`SpringJoints`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpringJoint.html) could be the thing you're looking for